# How to find all subscribed clients to a web socket destination in spring boot?

Tags: spring-boot, websocket, spring-websocket, java-websocket

I have a backend running on the spring boot. I have two destinations in my application `/user` and `/queue`. I want to print every subscriber on the screen whenever a client subscribes to the `/queue`.